# Access variables of classes when looping list of classes and getting an instance of Type

Tags: dart

I have this Python code:

```
def from_json(cls, data: dict, api: Optional[Overpass] = None) -> "Result":
    """
    Create a new instance and load data from json object.

    :param data: JSON data returned by the Overpass API
    :param api:
    :return: New instance of Result object
    """
    result = cls(api=api)
    elem_cls: Type[Union["Area", "Node", "Relation", "Way"]]
    for elem_cls in [Node, Way, Relation, Area]:
        for element in data.get("elements", []):
            e_type = element.get("type")
            if hasattr(e_type, "lower") and e_type.lower() == elem_cls._type_value:
                result.append(elem_cls.from_json(element, result=result))

    return result
```

and I want to convert this to Dart code. This is what I've come up with:

```dart
factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data, {Overpass? api}) {
    Result result = Result(api: api!);
    Type elemCls;
    for (elemCls in [Node, Way, Relation, Area]) {
      for (Map<String, dynamic> element in data["elements"]) {
        String eType = element["type"];
        if (eType.toLowerCase() == elemCls.typeValue) {
          result.append(elemCls.fromJson(element, result: result));
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My problems are `The getter '_typeValue' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.` and `The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.`. This is because `_typeValue` and `fromJson` belong to the classes `Node`, `Way`, `Relation` and `Area` and not to `Type` which is what I get with this for loop. What do I have to change to get this working like in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do `eType.toLowerCase() == elemCls.toString().toLowerCase()`.  However, `elem_cls.from_json(element, result=result)` cannot be directly done in Dart.  There is no way to generically instantiate an object with type `elemCls`.

What you instead could do is create a lookup table to map type names to constructors:

```dart
final _constructionTable = {
  "node": Node.fromJson,
  "way": Way.fromJson,
  "relation": Relation.fromJson,
  "area": Area.fromJson,
};

factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data, {Overpass? api}) {
    Result result = Result(api: api!);
    for (Map<String, dynamic> element in data["elements"]) {
      String eType = element["type"]!;
      var fromJson = _constructionTable[eType.toLowerCase()];
      if (fromJson != null) {
         result.append(fromJson(element, result: result));
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that this also would be a bit more efficient too, and it avoids relying on the specific strings generated for the Dart types.